# VSTO Outlook: Recreate the ctp again on the fly

Tags: wpf, outlook, vsto, wpf-controls, outlook-addin

I am in a particular scenario in which I am with the need to remove and then create the custom task pane again.

Initially I create it as below:

```
                myWinformsUC = new myWinformsUC();                        
                myCtp = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myWinformsUC, ctpTitle);
                myCtp.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionTop;
                myCtp.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
                myCtp.Height = DefaultCtpHeight;
                myCtp.Visible = true;
```

myWinformsUC and myCtp are global variables.

Under particular circumstances I need to delete and then create again the ctp so I use the previous instance of myWinformsUC used initially. I don't create another instance of it as it has some states that I need to keep. So I do exactly the same as above but without getting another instance of myWinformsUC. I previously successfully delete the ctp from Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes before adding it again (not shown here).

```
                myCtp = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myWinformsUC, ctpTitle);
                myCtp.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionTop;
                myCtp.DockPositionRestrict = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
                myCtp.Height = DefaultCtpHeight;
                myCtp.Visible = true;
```

myWinformsUC contains an elementhost container which in turn embeds an WPF user control.

For some reason that I don't know the wpf content inside the toolbar is not shown after deleting and creating it again. Any ideas?

Note: If I create a new instance of myWinformsUC when creating the ctp again, then wpf content is shown within the toolbar.

Comment: Does it work if you try to do the same in a Windows forms application with two separate windows?

Comment: Why not simply hide/show or destroy/delete controls on your CTP rather than nuke the whole CTP?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko The problem that I have is that if I change screen resolution and/or scale from the OS on the fly (without restarting Outlook) or even when I move Outlook window from one monitor to another, the wpf content (images, texts, etc.) get blurry and also sometimes some black strike lines in the edges of the wpf control appear. So I thought to destroy entire ctp and create it again from the scratch to see if that solves the issue because I have noticed that if I restart Outlook after changing display settings, the wpf content is shown correctly (no blurry, no black strike lines).

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev and DimitryStreblechenko, do you know if there is a way to avoid using an elementhost to integrate wpf content into the ctp? I think the elementhost is the root cause.

Comment: No, there is no other way of placing WPF UI in Office applications.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Finally I destroyed/deleted the controls on my CTP and re-created them again. They are now shown but they are displayed blurry (images and texts). Do you know what can be the problem of the blurry effect?

Comment: That sure sounds like a WPF bug that caches stale display data. I added WPF tag to you question.

Comment: Or you might want to try to reproduce this in a standalone WPF app and ask a separate WPF question without mentioning Outlook

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yep, i could create a pure standalone WPF app and try to reproduce it and ask another question here but the problem is that sometimes these issues only happens when you run into an environment such as Outlook which you don't have control on it and it is not "yours". Also i know that elementhost causes a lot of problems but in this case there is not possibility to remove it..... Also what you said that could be that WPF caches stale display data, it does make sense. Thank you very much for this idea.

Comment: Guys, another thing that I always ask myself and it is not related to this topic (sorry): out of curiosity, Outlook VSTO Add-ins can be considered a winforms app? or is another kind of app?

Comment: Kind of - Outlook itself is a regular Win32 native app, but it also embeds its own WPF controls. You do the same - embed a WPF control inside a WinForms control inside the ActiveX control provided by the VSTO run-time.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO (not Outlook) uses the Windows forms technology as a base for any UI customizations like [Office custom task panes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) or [Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022). So, you may create a sample Windows forms application to verify issues you meet in Outlook. If the issue is reproducible then it is not related to Outlook or VSTO. Here is what MSDN states:

> Although solutions created by using the Office development tools in Visual Studio are designed to work with directly with Windows Forms controls, you can also use WPF controls in your solutions. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is an alternative to Windows Forms for designing user interfaces.

UI development on top of WPF has never been easy in Office applications. You can find a lot of issues when dealing with a WPF UI embedded in Office applications.

Comment: It looks like a rendering issue, a visual glitch, a WPF bug I would say. I have used Visual Debuggers like Snoop to inspect at runtime to see where those black strike lines come from and from the list of controls that Snoop shows there is not any associated to that weird lines. I have played with borders in runtime using such tool in real time and it is not a problem from borders, etc. Definetely i am almost sure it is a WPF bug.Also I have noticed that the weird black strike line is always at the topmost, it looks like its z-order/index value is higher which makes it stay there in the front.

Comment: Also depending on the situation, which display settings you have, screen resolution and scale, if you resize Outlook window, that black strike line disappear. Or also it can happen that it appears, then you resize window and it disappears, and again you resize it and again appears.

Comment: It seems you have already faced with some issues when dealing with WPF in Office applications (Outlook in particular).

Comment: yep, I am continuously facing problems with that. What i see it is that integrating WPF into Outlook VSTO complicates the things a lot and one always have weird issues like this or similar. Honestly I have been working with pure WPF app for years and this weird issue never happened to me. Also the ElementHost container causes a lot of problems. I need to remove that weird black strike lines but as said, i tried a lot of solutions and none of them work, all end up with the same result, blurry things and weird black strike lines. Any more ideas on how to face it?

Comment: That is not the end unfortunately.

Comment: I have discovered that when Outlook window is full maximized, the black strike lines appear but when I resize the Outlook window and it is not maximized, that black strike lines disappear. So again, it looks like it is a WPF bug. Any ideas? What do you think?